# Live replacement for regular expressions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a code for live replacement of specific words in a text field as the user types.

I'm using regex and javascript:
The first array has the regular expressions to be found, and the second array has the words that should replace any them.

```
source = new Array(/\srsrs\s/,/\sñ\s/,/\snaum\s/,/\svc\s/,/\scd\s/,/\sOq\s/,/\soke\s/,/\so\sq\s/,
                /\soque\s/,/\soqe\s/,/\spq\s/,/\sq\s/,/\sp\/\s/g,/\spra\s/,/\sp\s/,/\stbm\s/,
                /\stb\s/,/\std\s/,/\sblz\s/,/\saki\s/,/\svlw\s/,/\smara\s/,/\sqlq\s/,/\sqq\s/,
                /\srpz\s/,/\smsm\s/,/\smto\s/,/\smtu\s/,/\sqro\s/,/\sqdo\s/,/\sqd\s/,/\sqnd\s/,
                /\sqto\s/,/\sqm\s/,/\sjah\s/, /\sc\/\s/,/\scmg\s/,/\s\+\sou\s\-\s/,/\sflw\s/,
                /\sxau\s/,/\sto\s/,/\sta\s/);
after = new Array("risos","não","não","você","cadê","o que","o que","o que","o que","o que","porque",
            "que","para","para","para","também","também","tudo","beleza","aqui","valeu","maravilhoso",
            "qualquer","qualquer","rapaz","mesmo","muito","muito","quero","quando","quando","quando",
            "quanto","quem","Já","com","comego","mais ou menos","falow","tchau","estou","está");
```

This is the function that does the replacement:

```
function replacement(){
for(i=0; i<source.length; i++){
    newtext = " "+document.getElementById("translation").value+" ";
    console.log(newtext);
    if(myregex = newtext.match(source[i])){
    newafter = after[i];
    rafael = myregex+" ";
    document.getElementById("translation").value = document.getElementById("translation").value.replace(rafael, newafter);
    }
}
}
```

My problem is every time the function is called to replace an expression with only one letter, the replacement is being made on the first occurrence of that letter, even within a word. I thought looking for that letter with `\s` before and after would solve it, but it didn't.

Comment: If you are replacing "live" while the user still types, you must execute the replacement on the string from before the use began typing, instead of the already-replaced result string again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "live replacement" you mean calling function replacement at each keystroke then \b at the end will not help you, you should indeed use \s. However in your replacement function your are adding a space to the text field value so your single character words are triggering the replacement.

Here is my refactoring of your code :

```
(function () { // wrap in immediate function to hide local variables
  source = [ [/\brsrs\s$/, "risos"], // place reg exp and replacement next to each other
             [/\b(ñ|naum)\s$/, "não"], // note combined regexps
             [/\bvc\s$/, "você"]
             // ...
           ]; // not also use of array literals in place of new Array

  document.getElementById ("translation"​​​​​​​).addEventListener ('keyup', function (ev) {
    var t =  this.value  // fetch text area value
      , m
      , i = source.length;

    while (i--) // for each possible match
      if ((m = t.match(source[i][0]))) { // does this one match ?
        // replace match : first remove the match string (m[0]) from the end of 
        // the text string, then add the replacement word followed by a space
        this.value = t.slice (0, -m[0].length) + source[i][1] + ' '; 
        return; // done
      }
  }, false);  
}) ();​
```

And the fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/jFYuV

Comment: Thanks! this works like a charm.
I don't really get the logic behind this line:
this.value = t.slice (0, -m[0].length) + source[i][1] + ' ';

Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Added some comments, hope they help. Thanks for the upvote. I also added a $ at the end of the RegExp's to ensure that you only replace strings at the end of the text; the user can go back and edit the text to whatever he wants without being bothered by the "translation".

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking only to match a word, you should put `\b` before and after (word boundary). This will ensure that you don't match parts of words. Also note that you are corrupting your regex by concatenating a string. Try this instead:

```
var in = document.getElementById("translation").value;
if( in.charAt(in.length-1) == " ") { // user has just finished typing a word
                                     // this avoids interrupting the word being typed
    var l = source.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) in = in.replace(source[i],after[i]);
    document.getElementById("translation").value = in;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `g` (global) modified to regexes so that it will replace all occurrences and use `\b` instead of `\s` to mark word boundaries.

```
source = new Array(/\brsrs\b/g,/\bñ\b/g, etc
```

On a side note, since all your regexes follow the same pattern it might be easier to just do:

```
source = new Array( 'rsr', 'ñ', 'naum', etc );

if( myregex = newtext.match( new Regexp( "\b"+source[i]+"\b", 'g' ) ) ) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In a [somewhat different style](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/FU8JV/), you could create a function that encapsulated the list of substitutions:

```
var substitutions = {
    "rsrs": "risos",
    "ñ": "não",
    "naum": "não",
    "vc": "você",
    // ...
};

var createSubstitutionFunction = function(subs) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in subs) {
        if (subs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys[keys.length] = key;
        }
    }
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + keys.join("\\b|\\b") + "\\b", "g");
    return function(text) {
        return text.replace(regex, function(match) {
            return subs[match];
        });
    };
};

var replacer = createSubstitutionFunction(substitutions);
```

You would use it like this:

```
replacer("Some text with rsrs and naum and more rsrs and vc")
// ==> "Some text with risos and não and more risos and você"
```